# Timetable viewer - Python 3.4

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, console

My [friend](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/149146/padraig-lawlor) and I, have made a timetable viewer in Python 3.4 for a mock timetable. The format is a 2 week school timetable with 5 daily lessons with each lesson having a room. We have tried to make it as object-oriented as possible, yet is the solution overkill? Our goal was to make the classes into a module so you can just `import timetable` and create your own `Lesson()` and `Day()` objects to make your own timetable. So, is our solution overkill, and any general feedback on the code?

```
class Lesson:
    def __init__(self, name, room):
        self.room = room
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return ('{}: {}').format(self.name, self.room)

class Day:
    def __init__(self, name, week, lessons):
        self.name = name
        self.week = week
        self.lessons = lessons
    def __repr__(self):
        return ((str([x for x in self.lessons]).replace('[', ' ')).replace(']', '')).replace(',', '\n')

physics = Lesson("Physics", "B27")
prod_des = Lesson("Product Design", "B2")
comp_sci = Lesson("Computer Science", "B14")
french = Lesson("French", "C9")
english = Lesson("English", "C11")
maths = Lesson("Maths", "T15")
private_study = Lesson("Private Study", "N/A") 
chem = Lesson("Chemistry", "B12")
engineering = Lesson("Engineering", "Off Campus") 
biol = Lesson("Biology", "B24")
add_math = Lesson("Additional Math", "T19")
games = Lesson("Games", "Sports Field")
re = Lesson("R.E.", "M20")
engineering_voc = Lesson("Engineering (Vocational)", "B2")

monday = Day("Monday", "Week 1",[physics, prod_des, comp_sci, french, english])
tuesday = Day("Tuesday", "Week 1", [english, maths, prod_des, physics, private_study])
wednesday = Day("Wednesday", "Week 1", [french, chem, comp_sci, engineering, engineering])
thursday = Day("Thursday", "Week 1", [french, private_study, biol, maths, english])
friday = Day("Friday", "Week 1", [comp_sci, prod_des, maths, add_math, games])

monday2 = Day("Monday", "Week 2",[maths, prod_des, biol, english, private_study])
tuesday2 = Day("Tuesday", "Week 2", [prod_des, french, chem, maths, private_study])
wednesday2 = Day("Wednesday", "Week 2", [comp_sci, physics, re, engineering, engineering])
thursday2 = Day("Thursday", "Week 2", [games, maths, biol, french, english])
friday2 = Day("Friday", "Week 2", [french, chem, engineering_voc, english, comp_sci])

days = { 1: monday, 2: tuesday, 3: wednesday, 4: thursday, 5: friday,
         6: monday2, 7: tuesday2, 8: wednesday2, 9: thursday2, 10: friday2
}

while True:
    while True:
        try:
            day = int(input("\nDay: "))
            if day in days.keys():
                day_obj = days[day]
                print(day_obj.name, day_obj.week)
                print(day_obj)
                break
            raise ValueError
        except:
            print("It has to be a number between 1 and 10")
    while True:
        again = input("Again? (y/n): ").lower()
        if again == "n":
            quit()
        elif again not in ["y", "n"]:
            print("Type 'y' or 'n'")
        elif again == "y":
            break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible improvements:

- [Don't use `__repr__` for a human readable version of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr). That is what `__str__` is for. When writing your own `__rerp__` you should aim to make `eval(repr(obj))` work.
- Rather than `str.replace`, you could `str.format` the values to the correct format. And so I'd change your `Day.__repr__` to something more like:

  ```
  def __str__(self):
      return '\n'.join(' {!s}'.format(x) for x in self.lessons)
  ```
- Rather than making two near duplicate loops, you could abstract the logic into one function, `get_input`. You could also make it so that it shows the user what input they are allowed to pick.

  This could be implemented as:

  ```
  def get_input(question, valid):
      question += '[{}] '.format('/'.join(valid))
      valid = set(valid)
      while True:
          answer = input(question).lower()
          if answer in valid:
              return answer
  ```
- I'd change `Day.__str__` so that it also displays the name and week.
- I'd rather [read a JSON file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), than build the week structure in your program. This is as you may want to later build a GUI, and allow other students to enter their time-tables.

  I'll leave this down to the both of you to look into. :)

Excluding the last bullet point I'd change your code to:

```
class Lesson:
    def __init__(self, name, room):
        self.room = room
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.name, self.room)

class Day:
    def __init__(self, name, week, lessons):
        self.name = name
        self.week = week
        self.lessons = lessons

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}\n{}'.format(
            self.name,
            self.week,
            '\n'.join(' {!s}'.format(x) for x in self.lessons)
        )

def get_input(question, valid):
    question += '[{}] '.format('/'.join(valid))
    valid = set(valid)
    while True:
        answer = input(question).lower()
        if answer in valid:
            return answer

days_str = [str(day) for day in sorted(days.keys())]
while True:
    day = get_input('Day: ', days_str)
    print(days[int(day)])
    if 'n' == get_input('Again? ', ['y', 'n']):
        break
```